# Backbone listenTo callback arguments

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and I'm confused by a snippet of the sample todo app code: http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html

On the `AppView` object there's a function called `addOne` that takes an argument:

```
addOne: function(todo) {
  var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
  this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
},
```

This function is called whenever the `add` event is triggered on the `Todos` model. There doesn't seem to be anything in here that tells the listener that it needs to pass in a `todo` argument to the `addOne` function:

```
this.listenTo(Todos, 'add', this.addOne);
```

When the event gets triggered and `this.addOne` is called, how does Backbone know to provide `addOne` with it's `todo` argument, since it doesn't seem to be specified in the `listenTo` invocation?

Comment: By any chance is Todos an instance of Backbone.Collection?

Comment: @KyleNeedham Yes it is.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Backbone.Collection.add` & `Backbone.Collection.create` will trigger the `add` event passing `model, this, options` as arguments like this.

`.trigger('add', model, this, options);`

`this.addOne` is then passed these arguments when called by `listenTo`.

Comment: The [Events Catalogue](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) in the docs covers this.